# how to append array into anoher array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var states = new Array();
var st = {'FL':{'profit':150}};
states.push(st);

alert(states[0]['FL']['profit']);
```

The problem with this is that I want to access variable like this  `alert(states['FL']['profit']);` , meaning without [0] index... But that [0] index is added by default by "push" method. And I really need to append array into array this way because I am assigning through the loop. So is there way to append to array without assigning that index [0] ?

Comment: Arrays have numeric indexes, objects have named properties. It sounds like you want to merge objects, not append to an array.

Comment: ok, well, how do I do that? is there a way that I can set up things so that I can access my variable this way states['FL']['profit'] ?

Comment: Yes: `states = st;` or iterate over the `st` object, with a `for...in` loop and append each of the properties (the `'FL'`) and their values (the `{'profit':150}`) to a new object `st` (created by `st = {}`). But if you want them in an array you have to deal with the necessity of accessing the objects, and properties, via array (and object) notation.

Comment: @vitaliimaximov Isn't that answered in the duplicate question?